# Book about a boy who befriends a Gruffalo-like monster

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about a boy who leaves his village, and goes on an adventure where he encounters several beast/monsters/creatures. One of the monsters he meets is a lot like the [Gruffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gruffalo) and also becomes somewhat of a companion to the boy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember anything about the book itself?  Was it a paperback, hardcover or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art or any character or place names?  Was the monster like the Gruffalo in appearance or in behaviour?

Comment: Not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Wild_Things_Are?

Comment: the book was paper back the main little boy was like an elf of some sort if i remember correctly. the monster was like the gruffalo in appearance but was very kind and soft hearted.

Comment: no it was a bigger book that were the wild things are and for an older age i think one of the monsters was a centipede or bug like creature with a pink bubble round its head